# How to have one function wait for another function to finish processing in javascript using chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I have a function that pulls an array from firebase via its rest api, which I need to input into another function to create a calendar.

```
function array_from_firebase(){
    //code that pulls from firebase
    return array
}

function calendar_create_from_array(array){
    //code that generates calendar
}
```

The following does not work:

```
calendar_create_from_array(array_from_firebase())
```

However, this does work

```
array = array_from_firebase()
setTimeout(calendar_create_from_array,9000,array)
```

I believe this means that array_from_firebase takes a bit of time longer than calendar_create_from_array  and calendar_create_from_array triggers too quickly.

How could I use chaining and promises to solve this?

Comment: can you post here the code in `array_from_firebase()`

Comment: Provide what you have done so far (as I assume, and your are supposed to, you did some research first)

Comment: The firebase docs should be clear in how to access the results

Comment: Both should not work. Whatever `array_from_firebase` does, it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first function you can return a promise. In this example usage of `setTimeout` is just to demonstrate that the next function execute after the first function

```js
function array_from_firebase() {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        return resolve([1, 2, 3])
      }, 4000)
    },
    function(reject) {})
}

function calendar_create_from_array(array) {
  console.log(array);
}

array_from_firebase().then(function(resp) {
  calendar_create_from_array(resp)
})
```

You can also use async & await.In this case the function which will wait for the result from another function need to be declared as `async` and declare `await` keyword before the function which will return the result.

```js
function array_from_firebase() {
  return new Promise(

    function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        return resolve([1, 2, 3])
      }, 5000)

    },
    function(reject) {})
}

async function calendar_create_from_array() {
  console.log('Calling function and waiting for result for 5secs....')
  let getResult = await array_from_firebase();
  console.log('Got result after 5secs', getResult)
}
calendar_create_from_array()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you work with asynchronous code, you usually deal with `Promise`s, which you have handle with `.then` and `.catch` blocks, to force you functions to wait for response. I've simulated the async call inside `array_from_firebase` function, it returns the response after 3 seconds, and the response is a `Promise`. Then you can handle this promise via `.then` block (as shown in `calendar_create_from_array` function), it will be executed, when you get the response with no errors, and `.catch` block will be executed when you get the error in response. Something like this:

```js
function array_from_firebase() {
  // Simulate async response
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve([1,2,3]);
    }, 3000);
  })
}

function calendar_create_from_array() {
    array_from_firebase()
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
}

calendar_create_from_array();
```